# How do you sort a 2D List in python?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of co-ordinates which indicate the top-left position (first two values) and the bottom right co-ordinates (the last two) of a detected word in an image

It looks something like this :

```
boxes= [[ 27,  22,  84 , 54],
     [261 ,127 ,294 ,163],
     [224 , 21 ,279 , 54],
     [ 45  ,83 , 96 ,111],
     [ 10 ,126 , 66 ,163],
     [189 ,185 ,219 ,222],
     [154 , 21 ,192 , 59],
     [278 , 25 ,318 , 58],
     [146 ,188 ,186, 220]]
```

so in boxes[0] would give me [27,22,84,54] and lets call them startX , startY , endX , endY respectively

For visualizing :

```
 (27,22)------------.
    '               '
    '               '
    '               '
    '---------------(84,54)
```

I need to sort this in a way that startY begins being minimum with increasing startX and startY incresaing

so the output must look something like this

```
     [[154 , 21 ,192 , 59],
     [224 , 21 ,279 , 54],
     [ 27,  22,  84 , 54],
     [278 , 25 ,318 , 58],
     [ 45  ,83 , 96 ,111],
     [ 10 ,126 , 66 ,163],
     [261 ,127 ,294 ,163],
     [189 ,185 ,219 ,222],
     [146 ,188 ,186, 220]]
```

Comment: Do you need to sort by startY in ascending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python will sort a tuple based on position, so you can pass a `key` to `sorted()` that puts the elements in the order you want to base the sort on:

```
boxes= [[ 27,  22,  84 , 54],
     [261 ,127 ,294 ,163],
     [224 , 21 ,279 , 54],
     [ 45  ,83 , 96 ,111],
     [ 10 ,126 , 66 ,163],
     [189 ,185 ,219 ,222],
     [154 , 21 ,192 , 59],
     [278 , 25 ,318 , 58],
     [146 ,188 ,186, 220]]

sorted(boxes, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0], x[2], x[3]))
```

Result:

```
[[154, 21, 192, 59],
 [224, 21, 279, 54],
 [27, 22, 84, 54],
 [278, 25, 318, 58],
 [45, 83, 96, 111],
 [10, 126, 66, 163],
 [261, 127, 294, 163],
 [189, 185, 219, 222],
 [146, 188, 186, 220]]
```

If you want to sort the list in-place use `boxes.sort()` with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what you want is to first sort for startX and then for startY, while respecting the relative order between elements in startX.
It would look like this:

```
# Input:
[[ 27,  22,  84 , 54],
 [261 ,127 ,294 ,163],
 [224 , 21 ,279 , 54],
 [ 45  ,83 , 96 ,111],
 [ 10 ,126 , 66 ,163],
 [189 ,185 ,219 ,222],
 [154 , 21 ,192 , 59],
 [278 , 25 ,318 , 58],
 [146 ,188 ,186, 220]]
# First sort:
[[ 10 ,126 , 66 ,163],
 [ 27,  22,  84 , 54],
 [ 45  ,83 , 96 ,111],
 [146 ,188 ,186, 220],
 [154 , 21 ,192 , 59],
 [189 ,185 ,219 ,222],
 [224 , 21 ,279 , 54],
 [261 ,127 ,294 ,163],
 [278 , 25 ,318 , 58]]
# Second sort:
[[154 , 21 ,192 , 59],
 [224 , 21 ,279 , 54],
 [ 27,  22,  84 , 54],
 [278 , 25 ,318 , 58],
 [ 45  ,83 , 96 ,111],
 [ 10 ,126 , 66 ,163],
 [261 ,127 ,294 ,163],
 [146 ,188 ,186, 220],
 [189 ,185 ,219 ,222]]
```

That's what's called a stable sort.
Now, according to the [standard library reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), the `sorted` function implements a stable sort.

Comment: Not complaining, but any reason for the downvote? There's no room for improvement without proper criticism.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks. The only one I could think of was that there was a better way (provided in a different answer), but I think that just merits no positive votes.